# device descriptor read/64, error -110

Tags: usb, debian

I have a storage server running openmediavault which is based on debian.
The OS is in a USB 3.0 Stick pluged directly on the motherboard (no USB-Hub or sth).
The system was running fine for about 3 Months and 2 days ago I got this errors:

```
usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 1-3: device not accepting address 33, error -110
usb 1-3: device not accepting address 34, error -110
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 3
```

When I restart the server, everything is fine again.
The next day I face the same error...

What can I do to fix this. I dont want to loose 3TB of data...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

USB error -110 means "Timeout expired before the transfer completed", which could be caused by anything. Most commonly, it's because power was exceeded; the host could not provide enough electric power for the pendrive to operate. Because it has not enough power also the USB stick cannot provide the device descriptor to the host, as a result it cannot be identified and so on. Maybe your motherboard it's overloaded with devices that consume all the available power.

Comment: So far it worked well, and the only things I have pluged into the MB are 3 SATA-HDDs and the CPU-Fan. Nothing that could drain so much power...

Comment: Hmmm, it depends... you have study the specs of the motherboard, the hdd and the CPU fan (even I don't think that fan drains a lot of power).

Comment: Off-topic. I once diagnosed a similar issue, an industrial computer board (which actually it was a former laptop line adjusted by Fujitsu-Siemens for industrial/medical use) and a FireWire industrial camera. This camera was reseting randomly. In fact all the peripherals were sharing the same power source, and in some situations the board was cutting the power to the camera, in order to suply it the more higher priority devices.

Comment: @garzanti : Same thing... I got -32 (please notify @ me as I don't check for answers manually)

Comment: This answer does not make sense to me. The failed device is an HP LaserJet printer and so it have its own power supply.

Comment: #define EPIPE       32  /* Broken pipe */

http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno is the URL

Comment: [Source](https://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html) `grep '110' /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h` (from linux-libc-dev) → `#define ETIMEDOUT 110 /* Connection timed out */`

Comment: @garzanti Could it also be related to hardware failure?

Comment: I had bluetooth mouse, so then I just wait (or unplug it)

Answer (score 16):

The problem was a USB 3.0 Stick that needed more current than usual for a USB 2.0 device.
This lead to the errors.
I replaced the stick and in addition to that I installed the latest BIOS-Drivers.
No more problems!

Answer (score 8):

Just to add another data point: I was running into "error -110" messages for my Inateck dual bay USB 3.0 to SATA device ([amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00N1KXE9K)). This fixed it for me:

1. `shutdown -h now` (turn off the computer)
2. Unplug USB device from computer.
3. Unplug power cord to back of the computer.
4. Unplug power to Inateck - pull wall wart plug **from wall socket**.
5. Noticed there was a green glowing LED on the Inateck wall wart; waited for that to go dark.
6. Waited ~3min total.
7. Plugged everything back in and booted up.

Worked liked a charm.

**Note**: Previously I tried just unplugging the computer and letting it sit for a while; that didn't work. I had to unplug the USB from the computer and the usb device power adapter from the wall.

Must be something with USB power provisioning/negotiation?

Comment: Thanks for that information.  I have had that _glowing LED_ thing with some NIVIDIA drivers on Linux, so I knew what you meant.  In my case I had plugged-in a powered USB hub before the power was connected.  I am surprised though that the Hub drew power before anything was connected.  Based on the comments here, seems the USB port status is locked at at 110 until whatever hot-start on-board memory loses power long enough to _forget_.  Like I said, seen that already with the graphics driver.  It is a relief to be back and running -- I couldn't see what might have gone awry.

Comment: I had the same problem, but I only needed to unplug and replug the power cable (while the PC is runnning). For some reason, simply rebooting the PC didn't help.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error, but with no USB device plugged in. I have a Suse 13.2 and 42.2 installed on an internal ssd drive in a HP ProBook 430. When I booted into 42.2, I got that error

> device descriptor read/64, error -110

and booting simply stopped there. Weird enough with 13.2 on the same hard disk I could boot with no problems.
Following Johnsters advice to unplug any power supply including battery removal finally did it, so loads of thanks go there.
And to all running into this post without any obvious interaction of USB devices in their problems: Try making your system voltage free, it still might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, it helped! I had similar circumstances: after running the official kernel upgrade (from 4.15.0-136 into -137) in my Ubuntu 16.04., I got the same error on booting. I could manage through the boot menu to successfully boot with the -136 kernel, I reinstalled the -137 kernel upgrade, and did as recommended in this answer: switch off the computer, and, to be sure, unplugged **everything** (keyboard, mouse, speakers, supply, any USB-bluetooth device, ...). After 5 minutes break I replugged, rebooted, and everything was fine. Thank God!

Answer (score 1):

Main voltage is not high enough in my home. It's below 180V (normally 220-240). Sometimes I get the same error. Sometimes my PC restarts itself.